# How to List all 32(2^5) combination of binary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting, visual-studio-2015

How generate all binary combination from 00000 -> 11111 using C# with the easiest way, Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Show us your attempt.

Comment: Easiest for who (or what)?

Answer (score 2):

An easy google search would probably gotten you the answer, but if you just want the binary representation of numbers from 0 to 32.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(5, '0'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i= 0; i < 32; i++)
{
  // i is a packed combination
  // j-th bit is (i >> j) & 1
}
```